# Web.Config not able to render special character

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a ASP.NET Web app and here is the below entry in Web.Config

```
<add key="FromName" value="Test™"/>
```

When I try to browse the site I get the following error-

Configuration file is not well-formed XML

It converts the above key to the below way-

```
<add key="FromName" value="Test�"/>
```

In IIS I have set the UTF-8 format. I have been trying to look for an answer for a quite long time.

Does somebody have any idea on the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use the ASCII value:

```
<add key="FromName" value="Test&#0153;" />
```

If this returns as `Test&#0153;`, then you'll have to encode the result.

Comment: What about when the inverse happens: you put Test&#0153; but this is shown: Test�. What could be the issue? Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the trademark xml entity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references